# Is there some 'cross apply' function in R?

Tags: r

Is there some function in R of the form like:

```
crossApply(v1, v2, func)
```

that has the same functionality as:

```
ret = c()
i = 1
for (e1 in v1) {
  for (e2 in v2) {
    ret[i] <- func(e1,e2)
    i <- i + 1
  }
}
return(ret)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you may be looking for `outer` which isn't exactly what your code does, but it's close. Specifically, `outer` will return the matrix (i.e. the outer product) or each combination of the elements of its first two arguments.

You'd probably want to store the result and then extract the lower triangle as a vector. Something like this maybe:

```
rs <- outer(1:4,-(5:7),"+")
rs[lower.tri(rs,diag = TRUE)]
[1] -4 -3 -2 -1 -4 -3 -2 -4 -3
```

Comment: Thanks ! How can I define a custom function to use in the outer ? Would you mind giving an example ? I keep getting errors when trying this, and my error messages are in Chinese so I guess posting them will be of little help.

Comment: @SpiritZhang : `emulatesum<-function(x,y) return(x + y)` as a function, and then `rs <- outer(1:4,-(5:7),"emulatesum")`. BTW: I strongly advise to use R in English, particularly for error messages: googling them is so much easier when you have them in English...

Comment: @NickSabbe: Thanks Nick! I didn't pay much attention to the language when I installed R. Since I'm in China I guess that's why R made Chinese the default language.

Answer (score 1):

An example

```
func <- function(x,y) {sqrt(x^2+y^2)}
v1 <- c(1,3,5)
v2 <- c(0,-4,-12)
ret <- outer(v1,v2,"func")
```

And you then have

```
> ret
     [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
[1,]    1 4.123106 12.04159
[2,]    3 5.000000 12.36932
[3,]    5 6.403124 13.00000
```

or if you want exactly what your for loops would produce

```
> as.vector(t(ret))
[1]  1.000000  4.123106 12.041595  3.000000  5.000000 12.369317  5.000000
[8]  6.403124 13.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly easy to do with `do.call` and `expand.grid`:

```
x <- seq(0,10, length.out=10)
> y <- seq(-1,1, length.out=5)
> d1 <- expand.grid(x=x, y=y)  
> do.call("*", d1)
 [1]   0.0000000  -1.1111111  -2.2222222  -3.3333333  -4.4444444
 [6]  -5.5555556  -6.6666667  -7.7777778  -8.8888889 -10.0000000
[11]   0.0000000  -0.5555556  -1.1111111  -1.6666667  -2.2222222
[16]  -2.7777778  -3.3333333  -3.8888889  -4.4444444  -5.0000000
[21]   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000
[26]   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000
[31]   0.0000000   0.5555556   1.1111111   1.6666667   2.2222222
[36]   2.7777778   3.3333333   3.8888889   4.4444444   5.0000000
[41]   0.0000000   1.1111111   2.2222222   3.3333333   4.4444444
[46]   5.5555556   6.6666667   7.7777778   8.8888889  10.0000000
```

Comment: Great, but note that only vectorized function can work with `do.call` in this case. e.g., do.call(mean, d1) fails.

Comment: so maybe it should be `do.call("mapply", c(fun, d1))`.

Comment: Interesting idea. It seems to do with `do.call(expand.grid(.))` what `Vectorize` does with `sapply`.